# Is it possible to have a hybrid gas/ice giant realistically? If so, what would it look like?

Tags: science-based, gas-giants

My solar system involves the inclusion of a sort of in-between gas and ice giant. Could this actually exist, or are gas and ice giants completely independent classification?

Comment: Please set your expectations. "What would it look like?" is a question type that gets closed a lot because there are almost always too many vaiables for a definitive answer. What contaminants are in the atmosphere of the planet? Are there differences in density? Do those differences vary by latitude? What type and temperature is the star casting the light? How far away from the star is the gas giant? Etc. etc. etc. All these things and more will affect what the planet "looks like," which is why questions like this are closed so often.

Comment: Can't you just have a ball of ice covered by a lot of gas. I mean i don't know if this covers the classification of a gas giant. But isn't this what you wanted @Pointy Orb.

Answer (score 4):

Gas giant, ice giant, rocky planet and so on are not hard coded laws of nature. They are just arbitrar-ish categories created by the minds of one species trying to classify and put order in the apparent chaos they observe in the nature around them, and as such subject to the caprice of the evidence provided by the observations on said nature.

Heck, I went through adolescence and I got, together with all the changes in my body, also a thing called dwarf planet popping out of the blue when someone decided that what I had been devouring in all astronomy books until that moment was not sufficient!

A planet with features belonging to different categories can exist. At the end we have the platypus as example: beak of a bird, produces milk like a mammal.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a gas giant and an ice giant is kinda vague. The interior of Neptune and Uranus are hot slushes of materials with a relatively high freezing point -- methane, water, and ammonia. This is compared to Jupiter and Saturn, which are failed stars made mostly of hydrogen and helium.

It isn't impossible to have a planet with a slushy core covered by a thick layer of hydrogen and helium, but I don't know what that would accomplish, or even how you'd be able to tell. There's a threshold where the heat of formation will no longer drive convection, and exceeding that threshold is theorized to be why Uranus lacks the banding of the inner planets.

So, possible, sure. What impact it would have on the appearance of the world is questionable.

Answer (score 1):

An ice giant is a giant planet composed mainly of elements heavier than hydrogen and helium. An ice giant likely formed differently, primarily by accretion of solid ice particles rather than gas, but there is no physical distinction beyond one sum of numbers being larger than another. There is really nothing to hybridize, just planets close to the defining threshold.